# Nodejs + express + mysql : Wish to create a customer profile page but end up all the path messed up

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I will try to describe my question well and what I trying to archieve

I have lots of table like this in my nodejs app
everying member I will give it a href to "/profile/"theirUsername""
[image]

after watching ton of tutorial,

I add a button href to my username

```
 $('#pendingDepositTable').append(`
            <tr>
            <td>
              <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                <div class="table-user-name ml-3">
                  <p class="mb-0 font-weight-medium">`+ response[i].id + `</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td>
            <a href="/profile/`+ response[i].customer + `">
            `+ response[i].customer + `
            </a>
            </td>
            <td>`+ response[i].bank + `</td>
            <td>`+ response[i].amount + `</td>
            <td>
              <div class="badge badge-inverse-warning"> `+ response[i].status + ` </div>
            </td>
            <td>`+ response[i].date + `</td>
            <td>
              <a href="/updateDepositStatus?depositID=`+ response[i].id + `" class="btn btn-success"><i class="mdi mdi mdi-check-all"></i></a>
              <a href="/rejectDeposit?depositID=`+ response[i].id + `" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-close"></i></a>
            </td>
          </tr>
            `)
    }
```

I add this in my profile.js

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res, next) {

console.log(req.params.id);

db.query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `username` = '" + req.params.id + "'", function (err, result, field) {
    try {
          res.render('templateMember', { customers_profile: result });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
})
```

Before I render the page, I use res.send(result) and get the data that I want successfully.

But all of my header and js script all messed up (I put these in partials.)

[image]

and the url all gone wrong

example my transaction page is http://localhost:3000/deposit
but if i redirect from here it become http://localhost:3000/profile/deposit
What can I do or if i miss something?

my projects folder

[image]

my app.js

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var flash = require('express-flash');

app.use(flash());


app.use(session({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true
}));


var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var loginRouter = require('./routes/user_signin');
var memberRouter = require('./routes/members');
var depositRouter = require('./routes/deposit');
var withdrawalRouter = require('./routes/withdrawal');
var creditTransferRouter = require('./routes/creditTransfer');
var cashBonusRouter = require('./routes/cashBonus');
var productListingRouter = require('./routes/products_listing');
var productBalanceRouter = require('./routes/products_balance');
var bankListingRouter = require('./routes/banks_listing');
var bankBalanceRouter = require('./routes/banks_balance');
var bonusRouter = require('./routes/bonus');
var profileRouter = require('./routes/profile')


// view engine setup

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// Login API
app.use('/auth', require('./routes/controllerRoute/auth'));
// Post Product API
app.use('/product_add_action', require('./routes/controllerRoute/product_add_action'));
// Add Member API
app.use('/addMemberRouter', require('./routes/controllerRoute/addMemberRouter'));


app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/userSignin', loginRouter);
app.use('/member', memberRouter);
app.use('/deposit', depositRouter);
app.use('/withdrawal', withdrawalRouter);
app.use('/credittransfer', creditTransferRouter);
app.use('/cashbonus', cashBonusRouter);
app.use('/products_listing', productListingRouter);
app.use('/products_balance', productBalanceRouter);
app.use('/banks_listing', bankListingRouter);
app.use('/banks_balance', bankBalanceRouter);
app.use('/profile', profileRouter);
app.use('/bonus', bonusRouter);


app.all('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.session)
})

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

Comment: your query is open to sql injection, why you not using placeholders?

Comment: i am new to this, may I know what is it?

Comment: rtm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql#escaping-query-values

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just found out the answer.

instead of using src="xxx.css"
it should be src="/xxx.css" The leading slash indicates that the request is relative to root not the path that is making the request.

Sorry for post the question without reviewing my code carefully.